# How can get the url and anchor of a page in java

Tags: java, information-retrieval

I have about one million urls. I want to extract their titles and their anchors.
In the other words, I want to extract their "title" tags text, without downloading that urls.
How can I do that?
can I use Selenium?How?

Comment: `extract their "title" tags text, without downloading that urls` that sounds impossible. As the `title` is part of the returned page you need to download it to get this information. Also for the anchors. If an anchor is on the last line of the page, you need to download the whole page first. You don't need to store it on the filesystem. If that's what you mean with downloading it. But without having a look at your code it can only be a guess.

Comment: Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest to use jsoup. Have a look at the [cookbook pages](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/) and those threads about [jsoup on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+jsoup). Start to code a bit and when you stuck open a new question (including the code you have done) and explain what is not working as you expect.

Comment: Allright,Tnx a lot.